# Trigger causing an Apex script unhandled trigger exception .. System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger : line 51

Tags: trigger

I am running into an error message when attempting to bulkify my trigger. The trigger is on a custom object, Account_Status_Monitoring__c, that has a lookup field, Account__c, to the Account object.  The trigger uses this field to query some data on two other custom objects, Financials__c & Risk_Factors__c.  However, I am getting a "...attempt to de-reference a null object.." message.

Here is the trigger:

```
trigger UpdateASMfmFinancials on Account_Status_Monitoring__c (before insert) {

  // Financials
  Map<Id,Financials__c> finMap = new Map<Id,Financials__c>();
  for(Account_Status_Monitoring__c asm : Trigger.new)
  {
    finMap.put(asm.Account__c, null);       
  }

  finMap.remove(null);
  finMap.putAll([SELECT 
          Id, 
          OG_Group_12_Mth_Avg_MTD_Sales__c, 
          OG_Group_MTD_Sales_Generic__c
      FROM 
          Financials__c 
      WHERE 
          Account__c IN :finMap.keyset()]);



  // Risk Factors
  Map<Id,Risk_Factors__c> rfMap = new Map<Id,Risk_Factors__c>();
  for(Account_Status_Monitoring__c asm : Trigger.new)
  {
    rfMap.put(asm.Account__c, null);
  }

  rfMap.remove(null);
  rfMap.putAll([SELECT 
          Id, 
          Stage__c, 
          Status__c,
          OSR_Comments__c,
          Competitor__c,
          Reason__c,
          Effective_Date__c,
          RecordType.Name,
          CreatedDate,
          LastModifiedDate
      FROM 
          Risk_Factors__c 
      WHERE 
          Account__c IN :finMap.keyset()]);


  for(Account_Status_Monitoring__c asm : Trigger.new)
  {
      if(finMap.containsKey(asm.Account__c) && asm.Account__c != null)
      {
          asm.fin_Group_12_Mth_Avg_MTD_Sales__c = finMap.get(asm.Account__r.Id).OG_Group_12_Mth_Avg_MTD_Sales__c;
          asm.fin_Group_MTD_Sales_Generic__c = finMap.get(asm.Account__c).OG_Group_MTD_Sales_Generic__c;
      }

      if(rfMap.containsKey(asm.Account__c))
      {
          asm.rf_Stage__c = rfMap.get(asm.Account__c).Stage__c;
          asm.rf_Status__c = rfMap.get(asm.Account__c).Status__c;
          asm.rf_OSR_Comments__c = rfMap.get(asm.Account__c).OSR_Comments__c;
          asm.rf_Competitor__c = rfMap.get(asm.Account__c).Competitor__c;
          asm.rf_Reason__c = rfMap.get(asm.Account__c).Reason__c;
          asm.rf_Effective_Date__c = rfMap.get(asm.Account__c).Effective_date__c;
          asm.rf_Record_Type__c = rfMap.get(asm.Account__c).RecordType.Name;
          asm.rf_Risk_Factor_Created_Date__c = rfMap.get(asm.Account__c).CreatedDate;
          asm.rf_Risk_Factor_Last_Modified_Date__c = rfMap.get(asm.Account__c).LastModifiedDate;
      }     
  }}
```

Line 51 is "asm.fin_Group_12_Mth_Avg_MTD_Sales__c = finMap.get(asm.Account__r.Id).OG_Group_12_Mth_Avg_MTD_Sales__c;"

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally checking `containsKey` will suffice to protect you from these errors. 
However, you subverted this protection with this loop:

```
for (MyObject__c asm : trigger.new)
    finMap.put(asm.Account__c, null);
finMap.putAll([/*query*/]);
```

Remove it and just do:

```
finMap = new Map<Id, Finances__c>([/*query*/]);
```

Comment: Thank you, Adrian Larson......this got rid of my error message but it is not populating the field with any data.


asm.fin_Group_12_Mth_Avg_MTD_Sales__c = finMap.get(asm.Account__r.Id).OG_Group_12_Mth_Avg_MTD_Sales__c;
    asm.fin_Group_MTD_Sales_Generic__c = finMap.get(asm.Account__c).OG_Group_MTD_Sales_Generic__c;